# XSLT To Find Repeating values while transforming

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <GUID>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <DateOfBirth>16/01/1988</DateOfBirth>
        <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <PlaceOfResidence>United Kingdom</PlaceOfResidence>
        <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
        <TableName>PersonDetails</TableName>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <DateOfBirth>01/01/1960</DateOfBirth>
        <FirstName>Harold</FirstName>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <PlaceOfResidence>United Kingdom</PlaceOfResidence>
        <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
        <TableName>PersonDetails</TableName>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <DateOfBirth>05/05/1955</DateOfBirth>
        <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <PlaceOfResidence>United States</PlaceOfResidence>
        <RowNumber>3</RowNumber>
        <TableName>PersonDetails</TableName>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <CoverType>Property</CoverType>
        <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
        <TableName>Covers</TableName>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <CoverType>Motor</CoverType>
        <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
        <TableName>Covers</TableName>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
        <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
        <CoverType>Liability</CoverType>
        <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        <Notes>some notes</Notes>
        <RowNumber>3</RowNumber>
        <TableName>Covers</TableName>
    </GUID>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to transform this into the following:

```
<data>
    <ContractName>Contract Name</ContractName>
    <ContractNumber>Auto</ContractNumber>
    <Table>
        <TableRow RowNumber="1" TableName="PersonDetails">
            <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
            <PlaceOfResidence>United Kingdom</PlaceOfResidence>
            <DateOfBirth>16/01/1988</DateOfBirth>
            <Active>true</Active>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="2" TableName="PersonDetails">
            <FirstName>Harold</FirstName>
            <PlaceOfResidence>United Kingdom</PlaceOfResidence>
            <DateOfBirth>01/01/1960</DateOfBirth>
            <Active>true</Active>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="3" TableName="PersonDetails">
            <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
            <PlaceOfResidence>United States</PlaceOfResidence>
            <DateOfBirth>05/05/1955</DateOfBirth>
            <Active>true</Active>
        </TableRow>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <TableRow RowNumber="1" TableName="Covers">
            <CoverType>Property</CoverType>
            <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="2" TableName="Covers">
            <CoverType>Motor</CoverType>
            <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="3" TableName="Covers">
            <CoverType>Liability</CoverType>
            <DateAdded>01/06/2017</DateAdded>
        </TableRow>
    </Table>
    <Notes>some notes</Notes>
</data>
```

I am only able to use XSLT 1.0.

So far I have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[(*)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<data>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</data>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which strips the `<NewDataSet>`, and `<GUID>` tags and replaces with `<data>`.

However I am unsure how to generate the 2 tables groupings, and also automatically* identify the repeating values: ContractName, Contract Number and Notes.

*Other repeating values could appear later.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: So if `PlaceOfResidence` was also exactly the same for each row in the table, you would want to omit it?

Comment: Hi, No PlaceOfResidence should be repeated in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the challenge here is that you've got a flat list of `GUID` elements, that you need to group by `TableName` values.  This seems to be a pretty classic fit for Muenchian grouping, a technique described in detail over on Jenny Tennison's website: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Here is some XSL code that produces output almost identical to your desired XML format -- the only difference is in the order of elements within `<TableRow>`.  However, there are a number of unclear aspects of this transformation.  I've pointed out these issues in the code comments.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Avoids newline whitespace where source elements are excluded from output -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- The input XML appears to be a flat-ish list of `GUID` elements,
    each of which represents a single row of data in any of various tables. 
    In reorganizing this data, we want to group by `GUID/TableName` values.
    Muenchian grouping is probably the best way to do this in XSLT 1.0:
    see more at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.
    This requires a key, so before we try to process the `GUID`s, we set 
    up the key. -->
<xsl:key name="table" match="GUID" use="TableName"/>

<!-- Begin at the beginning: the root and topmost element. -->
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <data>
        <!-- I see in your desired output XML that you've put
            `ContractName` and `ContractNumber` just under the
            top-level `data` element.  This appears to assume
            that ALL of these have the same value for ALL of
            the individual `GUID` recordsets.
            In your input XML, these two are elements under `GUID`,
            so these data fields are included in the individual data
            records.  NOTE: If there is *any* chance that the values
            in these fields might differ between records, these
            should be kept within the table rows, and *not* moved
            to the same level as the output `Table` elements. -->
        <!-- This just naively copies these two elements from the first 
            `GUID` that has them.
            Again, if these values have any chance of differing between 
            `GUID`s, this whole approach is flawed. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="GUID[ContractName][1]/ContractName"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="GUID[ContractNumber][1]/ContractNumber"/>

        <!-- We want to process `GUID`s after grouping by `TableName` values.
            This `for-each` is part of the Muenchian grouping technique.  See
            Jenny Tennison's page (linked above) for a detailed explanation. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="GUID[count(. | key('table', TableName)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- If you wanted to sort alphabetically by TableName, you'd use:
                <xsl:sort select="TableName" /> -->
            <Table>
                <!-- Now, within each `table`, we want to process all those
                    `GUID`s with this same corresponding `TableName`. -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('table', TableName)">
                    <!-- We select "this", since we want to process the matching
                        `GUID`, not just its children. -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Table>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- This just copies the `Notes` element from the first `GUID` that has a 
            `Notes` child.
            Similar to `ContactName` and `ContactNumber`, this naively assumes that
            all `Notes` elements have identical content. This approach is flawed if
            there is *any* possibility of different values. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="GUID[Notes][1]/Notes"/>
    </data>

</xsl:template>

<!-- List up the elements we don't want to copy verbatim into each table row -->
<xsl:variable name="nocopy">
    <item>ContractName</item>
    <item>ContractNumber</item>
    <item>Notes</item>
    <item>RowNumber</item>
    <item>TableName</item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="GUID">
    <TableRow RowNumber="{RowNumber}" TableName="{TableName}">
        <!-- Copy over child data, but _only_ if it's not in `$nocopy` -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(name() = $nocopy/item)]"/>
    </TableRow>
</xsl:template>
```

### Update

Re-reading the text in your post (and not just your code :) ), I see that you're asking how to identify elements that are duplicate.  However, your desired XML output appears to already assume that the `ContractName`, `ContractNumber`, and `Notes` elements *must* be identical between all `GUID` structures.

This is confusing.  Your desired output already assumes the answer to your question.

Do you instead mean to ask, *"how do I identify any `GUID` child elements that are common to all `GUID` structures, and create a single top-level copy of these, while removing them from the output `GUID` structures?"*

### Update 2

It is pretty easy in XSL to determine if a given element is present anywhere in a set of XML structures.

It's not that easy to determine if a given element is present in **each** of a set of XML structures.  However, while ugly, it is possible.  :)

Replace the XSL above with the following.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Avoids newline whitespace where source elements are excluded from output -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- The input XML appears to be a flat-ish list of `GUID` elements,
each of which represents a single row of data in any of various tables. 
In reorganizing this data, we want to group by `GUID/TableName` values.
Muenchian grouping is probably the best way to do this in XSLT 1.0:
see more at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.
This requires a key, so before we try to process the `GUID`s, we set 
up the key. -->
<xsl:key name="table" match="GUID" use="TableName"/>
```

This `$kids` variable is the key portion where we determine which `GUID` children are common to all `GUID` structures.  There might be a more elegant and efficient way of doing this in XSL 1.0; running this against your small dataset takes 0.8 seconds in Oxygen XML (using the Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7 processor).

```
<!-- Build list of unique GUID children that appear in all GUID structures -->
<xsl:variable name="kids">
    <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/GUID/*">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <!-- Intermediate variable used to collect results of whether the
            given child is in each GUID -->
        <xsl:variable name="in_all">
            <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/GUID/*">
                <xsl:if test="name($this) = name(.) and $this = .">
                    <result><xsl:value-of select="true()"/></result>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- If we have the same number of `result`s as we have number of GUIDs,
                then output the first of each such child (there are dupes otherwise). -->
        <xsl:if test="count($in_all/result) = count(/NewDataSet/GUID) and 
         not(.=preceding::*)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$this"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

This portion is mostly the same, except for the bit about `$kids`.

```
<!-- Begin at the beginning: the root and topmost element. -->
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <data>
        <!-- We'll put common elements at the top of the `data` structure. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$kids"/>

        <!-- We want to process `GUID`s after grouping by `TableName` values.
        This `for-each` is part of the Muenchian grouping technique.  See
        Jenny Tennison's page (linked above) for a detailed explanation. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="GUID[count(. | key('table', TableName)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- If you wanted to sort alphabetically by TableName, you'd use:
            <xsl:sort select="TableName" /> -->
            <Table>
                <!-- Now, within each `table`, we want to process all those
                `GUID`s with this same corresponding `TableName`. -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('table', TableName)">
                    <!-- We select "this", since we want to process the matching
                    `GUID`, not just it's children. -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>

</xsl:template>
```

Updated `$nocopy` to include the element names identified by `$kids`.

```
<!-- List up the elements we don't want to copy verbatim into each table row -->
<xsl:variable name="nocopy">
    <item>RowNumber</item>
    <item>TableName</item>
    <!-- Copy in the bits from $kids -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$kids/*">
        <item><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="GUID">
    <TableRow RowNumber="{RowNumber}" TableName="{TableName}">
        <!-- Copy over child data, but _only_ if it's not in `$nocopy` -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(name() = $nocopy/item)]"/>
    </TableRow>
</xsl:template>
```

This now produces output functionally identical to your desired output XML.  The only difference is the order of elements -- the `TableRow` children are in a different order, and `Notes` is at the top of `data` alongside `ContractName` and `ContractNumber`, instead of at the bottom of `data`.

#### Notes about the output XML data format

It seems a bit odd to have the name of the table included as an attribute on each table row.  It would make more sense to have that as an attribute on the `Table` element itself.

Similarly, it seems redundant to have a `RowNumber` attribute on each row.  This information can be gleaned simply by looking at the `position()` of each `TableRow` within its parent `Table`.

That said, you know your requirements.  It's then simply a matter of getting things to work right.  :)

Comment: Hi, Firstly thank you for your quick reply! In reply to your question:"how do I identify any GUID child elements that are common to all GUID structures, and create a single top-level copy of these, while removing them from the output GUID structures?" Yes. That is exactly what i am after. These items will always be repeated with identical properties. This is in addition to what you have already provided, generating the Tables.